# Websocket authentication in Wildfly with RolesAllowed

Tags: java, websocket, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

I have a web socket defined using standard annotation like so

```
@ServerEndpoint("/mySocket")
@Singleton
public class myWebsocket {

@Inject
private MyEjb myEjb;

@OnMessage
public void message(Session session, String msg) { ...
```

Even though my user has logged in, I get access exceptions when calling myEjb because it doesn't recognize my user. If I check the principal of my session object

```
session.getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

the correct user is found, however, if I check the jboss SecurityContext class, I see an anonymous user

Comment: looks similar to the issue described here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/240617?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

This is a known deficiency in Java EE 7 WebSocket specification, see [the following issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/websocket-api/issues/238) in their bug-tracker.

However, there is a workaround available, see the [JBoss Security Extended](https://github.com/panga/jboss-security-extended) project and [this example](https://github.com/panga/websocket-auth/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/panga/websocket/auth/WSEndpoint.java).